# how to test that fullCalendar has been initialized using Konacha

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, konacha

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases) in a Rails application and want to test the pages that I'm using it on using [Konacha](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha).

In a file called `fullcal_init`, I have the following (working) code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        //do stuff with fullCalendar

    });

});
```

which generates `<div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr" ... ></div>`

I'm trying to test it with the following code:

```
#test_helper

//= require jquery
//= require chai-jquery
//= require "application"

...

#my_tests.js

//= require "test_helper"

var $ = jQuery

"use strict";

describe('fullcalendar_init', function() {

    it('renders the fullCalendar event stream', function() {
        ('#konacha').fullCalendar;
        assert.ok($('#konacha').should.have.class('fc'));
    });

});
```

this isn't working however - the Konacha test body doesn't have any classes appended to it.  There's not a lot of documentation about using Konacha (especially outside of a `backbone.js` context) - can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to test that `fullcalendar` is being initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  got this working by using the `done` callback that comes with [`mocha`](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/).  The problem was that `fullcalendar` takes some time to render, but my test was firing immediately, so there was no time for the `fc` class to be appended.  Put another way, my code is asynchronous and my test was not.  The following code works:

```
it('renders fullCalendar plugin', function(done) {
    $('#konacha').fullCalendar();
    done();
    $('.fc').should.exist;
});
```